# How to program an android rom for DroidX

Tags: android, rom

I was wondering if there were any places to look for help on how to make a custom ROM for my Droid X. I do not know where to start though. I know some JAVA and am learning more. I just do not know how to code it. Where to start AOSP, Stock edits, or 2nd init? Any tips welcome! I will also later code for the Galaxy Nexus, when I get it. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

2nd Init is the way to go. In order to this do though, you have to make sure that you have a pretty beastly comptuer as compiling the code can take upwards of 24 hours depending on your system.

Comment: Okay, I will do that. Where can I look for some guidance for this? I know some java but I'm  not amazing with it. Are there some simple tutos? And how to implement the 2nd init? Thanks!

Comment: Here is the official documentation on how to get started. http://source.android.com/source/initializing.html . Its only possible on Linux/iOS at the moment. And you need to be pretty good with C++ as well, and familiar with JDK. http://source.android.com/source/initializing.html